# Entering 32-bit protected mode does not work as intended

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm, osdev, protected-mode

So recently, I decided to try using 32-bit code instead of 16-bit code for my basic OS kernel. I tried to enter 32-bit protected mode, but it doesn't seem to work correctly. I use NASM for building and qemu for debugging, but when I debug it, the qemu window begins to glitch a lot.

And it keeps glitching in what seems to be consistent bursts every half a second.

This is my kernel's code:

```
bits 32
org 0x7E00

 ; attempting to enter 32 bit protected mode
cli
lgdt [gdtr]
mov eax, cr0
or al, 1
mov cr0, eax
jmp 08h:kernel_main

gdt_start:
    dq 0x0
gdt_code:
    dw 0xFFFF
    dw 0x0
    db 0x0
    db 10011010b
    db 11001111b
    db 0x0
gdt_data:
    dw 0xFFFF
    dw 0x0
    db 0x0
    db 10010010b
    db 11001111b
    db 0x0
gdt_end:
gdtr:
    dw gdt_end - gdt_start
    dd gdt_start

 ; main kernel code

kernel_main:
     ; Display hi in grey at top of screen
    mov dword [0xb8000], 0x07690748
    hlt
    ret
times 1024-($-$$) db 0
```

It is supposed to display "Hi" in grey at the top of the screen, but that doesn't seem to be working.
I did some tests and found out that it probably has something to do with the way I tried to enter 32-bit protected mode. I searched everywhere online, but I couldn't find anything that works.

Answer (score 1):

Only put your `bits 32` directive where the protected mode code actually starts. And once that happens, load the segment registers from the *gdt_data* selector. You might want to zero the upper 16 bits of the `ESP` register as well.

To save some space, you can put the GDT pointer over the NULL descriptor.
Do note that the correct GDT limit is `gdt_end - gdt_start - 1`

```
bits 16
org 0x7E00

    ; attempting to enter 32 bit protected mode
    cli
    lgdt  [gdtr]
    mov   eax, cr0
    or    al, 1
    mov   cr0, eax
    jmp   08h:kernel_main

gdt_start:
gdtr:
    dw gdt_end - gdt_start - 1
    dd gdt_start
    dw 0
gdt_code:
    dw 0xFFFF
    dw 0
    db 0
    db 10011010b
    db 11001111b
    db 0
gdt_data:
    dw 0xFFFF
    dw 0
    db 0
    db 10010010b
    db 11001111b
    db 0
gdt_end:

bits 32

kernel_main:
    ; main kernel code
    mov   eax, 0x10
    mov   ds, eax 
    mov   es, eax
    mov   fs, eax
    mov   gs, eax
    mov   ss, ax
    movzx esp, sp

    ; Display hi in grey at top of screen
    mov   dword [0xB8000], 0x07690748
    jmp   $

times 1024-($-$$) db 0
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to initialize the segment registers after the far jump to protected mode.
Change you kernel_main to something like this

```
kernel_main:
    mov eax, 0x10
    mov ds, eax 
    mov es, eax
    mov fs, eax
    mov gs, eax
    mov ss, eax

     ; Display hi in grey at top of screen
    mov dword [0xb8000], 0x07690748
    hlt
    ret
```